# How to configure AWS lambda function to perform crud operation on dynamodb tables in different aws sub-account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

In lambda functions we have version and aliases, I have two aliases (test1, test2). test1 does the crud operation on dynamodb within same account while test2 needs to perform crud on dynamodb in different sub-account same region(to prevent rework in lambda function).

How I tried:

1. created a role in main account to assume role
2. created a role in sub account will full aws service access
3. copied arn and assigned the sub account role to main account sts assume policy
4. test the lambda function to fetch data from sub account dynamodb table
5. error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::123456:assumed-role/getAccessSubAccountRole/testlambdafunction is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:region:123456:table/USER",
  "errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
    "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is listing the issue:

> User:
>   arn:aws:sts::123456:assumed-role/getAccessSubAccountRole/testlambdafunction
>   is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:region:123456:table/USER

In #2 you mentioned "created a role in sub account will full aws service access" but I think you should double check that this role has the access you expect.  Does this mean is had administrator access?  Once you're sure it has the access, check [how policies are evaluated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).

Comment: The role has been assigned with full aws access, so it will allow consumption of any aws services to which it is assigned to. The lambda function in same region uses that role and it works. Same role when assumed from main account it does not work, hence the issue.